# How to check what part of an gameobject is seen by a camera?

Tags: unity, c#, camera, raycasting, viewport

Could anyone please give me a hint on how to determine how much of an object is seen by a camera. There have to be a threshold value (e.g. 30% of an object is seen). If value is below the threshold then I don't cast rays otherwise I will do.
Now I am using WorldToViewPoint-function w.r.t. center of an object, but it doesn't working properly in my view.

Comment: Have you considered intersecting its renderer's bounds with the camera's frustum planes?

Comment: I am new in Unity and C# and I don't know yet this stuff. Thank you for your hint I try digging there.